# GLEW/GLUT: After calling init and creating a window, deinitialize and re-init?

Tags: c++, opengl, glut, glew

Essentially, I am attempting to discover the controls of the GLEW-GLUT setup.  The first objective here is the "hello-world" case where a window is initialized:

```
int argc = 0;
char ** argv = (char **) calloc(1,sizeof(char **));
argv[0] = (char *) calloc(1,sizeof(char *));
argv[0][0] = '\0';

glutInit(&argc, argv);
glutInitWindowSize( 500, 500);
glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100);

glutCreateWindow("foo");

std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));

glutDestroyWindow(glutGetWindow());

free(argv[0]);
free(argv);
```

From a "controls" perspective, it seems as if I cannot achieve a runtime state that existed prior to calling `glutInit` in the sense that I cannot "re-initialize" glut without getting a segmentation fault.

So, once glut is initialized, it appears as if glut is always initialized. This seems strange.

---

How does one tear everything down after GLUT is initialized, so that it can be re-initialized? Every method and setting I have tries leaves a window that will not close until the code exits.

There must be some sort of "GLEW/GLUT Teardown and Exit Everything" function...?

Or is every GLEW/GLUT window a one way ticket?

Comment: Gotta call `glutMainLoop()` to meaningfully process window events like closing.  But there's no coming back from that function as [specified](https://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/spec3/node14.html).  If you want slightly more application lifecycle control you'll want to switch to [FreeGLUT's extended API](https://github.com/dcnieho/FreeGLUT/blob/git_master/freeglut/freeglut/include/GL/freeglut_ext.h).  Or better yet, [GLFW](https://www.glfw.org/).

Comment: @genpfault GLFW is much better/more modern C than FreeGlut.  I don't know why it is not mentioned in any of the starting-up guides. I am replacing FreeGlut entirely, throughout the project -- it is that much better.  With a lack of control in FreeGlut, test driven development was becoming a slugfest.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, freeglut cannot cause a segmentation fault on re-initialization. It will simply notify you of this attempt and terminate the program, but this is *not* a segmentation fault.

Secondly, yes, it is possible to deinitialize and reinitialize freeglut. The `fgDeinitialize()` function should do this.

Something like this:

```
void fgDeinitialize( void ); // put it above main function
    
int main (int argc, char** argv, char** env) 
{ 
    int Window, i = 0; 
    glutInit(&i, NULL); // i don't want send arguments
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_ALPHA); 
    Window = glutCreateWindow("frog"); // init window
    glutDestroyWindow(Window); // destroy window
    printf("reinitialize freeglut\n");
    fgDeinitialize(); // destroy glut
    glutInit(&i, NULL); // initialize it again
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_ALPHA);
    glutInitWindowSize(1024, 768);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100);
    Window = glutCreateWindow("Second Window!");
    if (!Window) exit(-1); // if no window returned - error
    ... some other code ...
```

Comment: Could the program termination cause a seg fault?

Comment: In other words, if I knew the root cause rather than just the symptoms, would I have had a question?